Reanimated Error with the new React native architecture
I am getting this error using the latest Reanimated  with the new react native architecture. I have been struggling for the past 2 days. The error only occurs on Android.
ReanimatedError: [Reanimated] Native part of Reanimated doesn't seem to be initialized

Here is my package.json
{
  "name": "RNPlayground",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^7.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^7.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^7.2.0",
    "camelcase-keys": "^9.1.3",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "snakecase-keys": "^8.0.1",
    "zustand": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.25.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.25.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.76.4",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.76.4",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.76.4",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.76.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}


Here is my metro.config.js
const {getDefaultConfig, mergeConfig} = require('@react-native/metro-config');
const {wrapWithReanimatedMetroConfig} = require('react-native-reanimated/metro-config')

 
const config = {};

 module.exports = wrapWithReanimatedMetroConfig(
                     mergeConfig(getDefaultConfig(__dirname), config)
                 )

I have tried most online solutions but did not work for me. How do I fix this? Please help.
